# Insert data in a sheet based on data in other sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a Sheet 1 where data is inserted on a daily basis and a Sheet 2 where I need to insert specific values based on the data inserted in Sheet 1.

There are two ID's that can be used to identify the rows. There are three values that can be inserted in Sheet 2.

The first two values directly relate to specific data in Sheet 1 while the third is used for any other data. There are 25 cells per ID where data is inserted.

So if ID 1 has either values `A` or `B` in all 25 cells in Sheet 1, I need to insert the value `1` or `2` in Sheet 2.

If ID 1 doesn't have those values in all the cells, I need to insert the value `3`.

I need a way to automatically check, based on one or both of the ID's,
whether the values in Sheet 1 are all `A`, all `B` or anything else and insert one of the three values in Sheet 2.

I hope this is understandable enough. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

In the first part you can see where the data is input. There are 25 cells for data. I have put in the three different types of data used(all *k*,all *p*, or a combination of letters.)

In the second part you can see where the values are inserted in sheet 2. In *value* a number is inserted, based on which of the 3 types of data was input in sheet 1.

[image: Screenshot of worksheet]

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Editing your question and adding a screenshot will make it more understandable.

Comment: For better understanding upload sample data bcoz the longer test creates nothing but lots of confusion. Welcome to Super User !